# Handling tweepy connection issues when paginating cursors

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy to grab some conversations from twitter. Tweepy has a nasty habit of breaking if there's a connection problem, so I'm trying to handle this and keep retrying if there's a connection problem, but I have a hard time figuring out how to do this while paging through a cursor.

Here is my code:

```
chains = []
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='the&filter:replies', count=100).items():
    try:
        status_chain = get_status_chain(api, status.id_str)
        if len(status_chain) > 9:
            chains.append(status_chain)
    except Exception as e:
        # We hit a private message or a connection issue, skip to the next.
        print('Error: {error}. Retrying.'.format(error=e), file=sys.stderr)
        continue
    print(len(chains))
    if len(chains) > 99:
        break
```

There are two issues here. The big problem is that the try/except only covers calls made in `get_status_chain()`. If something goes wrong in the `for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='the&filter:replies', count=100).items()` line, the exception will be unhandled and my program will stop. If an error occurs here, I'd like to keep retrying at the same point, i.e. not start the whole for loop again.

The second issue is that if we hit a connection issue, I'd really like to retry getting the same chain again rather than just going to the next, but I'm not sure how to do this cleanly.

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: No, I just ended up skipping if there's a connection issue. I believe the problem I had at the time was that the response you got from a connection issue was the same as if you ran into a private message, so there was no way to differentiate. I don't know if that's changed now or if I was missing something.